# Import Users and user groups from LDAP in Liferay 6.1

Tags: import, ldap, liferay

I am trying to import LDAP user and groups into Liferay 6.1.

Following `portal-ext.properties`, can import only users not `Usergroups` from LDAP

Are there any suggestions please.

**`portal-ext.properties`**

```
ldap.auth.enabled=true
ldap.export.enabled=false
ldap.import.method=user
ldap.user.impl=com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.LDAPUser
ldap.server.ids=1

ldap.server.name.1=STAFF
ldap.base.provider.url.1=ldap://X.X.X.X:XXX
ldap.base.dn.1=ou=ABCD,ou=wdf,o=aaa
ldap.security.principal.1=cn=XXXX,ou=users,o=aaa
ldap.security.credentials.1=XXXXX

ldap.auth.search.filter.1=(mail=@email_address@)
ldap.import.user.search.filter.1=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(!(loginDisabled=true)))
ldap.user.mappings.1=screenName=cn\npassword=userPassword\nemailAddress=mail\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sn\ngroup=groupMembership\njobTitle=title
ldap.user.custom.mappings.1=university=company

ldap.import.group.search.filter.1=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(!(loginDisabled=true)))
ldap.group.mappings.1=groupName=company\ndescription=description\nuser=groupMembership
```

Error Message:
Got Error:

```
   ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-2][PortalLDAPImporterImpl:698] Unable to import user cn=xxxx: null:null:{cn=cn: xxxx}
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl.importGroup(PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java:753)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl.importGroups(PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java:849)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl.importFromLDAPByUser(PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java:693)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl.importFromLDAP(PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java:198)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl.importFromLDAP(PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java:135)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterImpl.importFromLDAP(PortalLDAPImporterImpl.java:95)
at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPImporterUtil.importFromLDAP(PortalLDAPImporterUtil.java:39)
at com.liferay.portlet.admin.messaging.LDAPImportMessageListener.doReceive(LDAPImportMessageListener.java:28)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
at $Proxy285.receive(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.messaging.SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.receive(SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.java:73)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:63)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:114)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:671)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:582)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

user is importing but still user group is not importing

Advance thanx

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check this:
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/15751010

I had the same error too, changing screenname mapping to uid from cn solved my issue. cn can contain space, I assume that was my problem.

Regards,
 Balint

Comment: So cn should not contain space?

Comment: It is quite an old thread, but I think you should use UID instead of CN when syncing groups.
Probably you can use CN too if there are no spaces in them.

Comment: #ldap.user.mappings=screenName=cn\npassword=userPassword\nemailAddress=mail\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sn

ldap.user.mappings=screenName=displayName\npassword=userPassword\nemailAddress=mail\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sn

Comment: In the property file i made changes given above. May be i should try with with ui instead of displayName

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pay special attention to the following properties in `portal.properties`:

```
#
# Set either user or group for import method. If set to user, the portal
# will import all users and the groups associated with those users. If set
# to group, the portal import all groups and the users associated those
# groups. This value should be set based on how your LDAP server stores
# group membership information.
#
ldap.import.method=user
#ldap.import.method=group // may be you can use this

#
# If set to true, the group filter will be applied, but only to groups in
# the specified base DN. If set to false, the filter will not be applied and
# all groups that are associated with the imported users will be imported
# regardless of the base DN.
#
ldap.import.group.search.filter.enabled=true
```

Also I think you can test whether groups are being imported or not by going to the Control panel and then ...

1. Control Panel
2. Portal Settings
3. `Authentication` tab
4. `LDAP` tab
5. Click "Add" or "Edit" (if LDAP already added)
6. Go to `Groups` section and add relevant mapping information, click `Test LDAP Groups` (screen shot attached).

[image]

Hope this may help you in some way.

Comment: Hi Prakash, Thank you for the reply,

I have checked by clicking on 'Test LDAO Groups' button I can see around 10 groups but while importing its not importing User Groups its only importing users

Thank you,
krishna

Comment: Did you try using: `ldap.import.method=group`?

Comment: Yes, I did try using  ldap.import.method=group,  but no use